# Website hosting query

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis-7, windows-server-2008

I have a Asp.Net MVC 1.0 website hosted in C: drive of the application server. If I shift the same in the E: drive which is having much more space than the C: drive whether I get any performance increase?

One more query is that I am using a lot of Innumerable to store my data fetched from DB, where these data will be stored? Server or Client and in which drive? drive where website is hosted or always in C: drive?

Comment: I am not clear about your question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Disk performance is based on the speed of the disks and how busy they are.  Generally disk IO isn't an issue with common web applications, although for very busy sites they can be.

If you are worried about performance and believe that it's disk related, check out Performance Monitor -> Physical Disks -> %Idle Time, Disk Queue Length, reads/sec, writes/sec, transfers/sec.

As for where the innumerable data is, it depends on what you do with it.  If you filter your queries as you call them from the database then it's the database engine that does the initial work (usually best).  That will use both CPU and disk IO.

If you further innumerate it from within code, then it's the CPU that will do the work.

If you happen to filter it client-side using Javascript, then it will use extra bandwidth and will do the processing on the client.

Comment: Thank you Scott! But I have one question; Disk IO means always C: drive where the OS is there or the E: drive where I want to host the website?

Comment: HI Arup.  Disk IO is Disk Input/Output.  In this context, IO refers to how much busy the disk is.  Unless you have performance problems, I would put the website on the disk that has the most space.  Performance is rarely your concern for the website part of your site.